# Change 'new item' fields in accordance to different views Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, form

I was wondering if there is a way to change the fields that appear when a user clicks 'new item' in a SharePoint list depending on what SharePoint view they are in.

For example, in 'end user view' only select fields will be shown in the item form, and in another view 'backend view' different fields will be shown when they click 'new item'

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint Online out of the box capabilities.

You need to create custom forms to achieve such kind of functionalities. I would recommend creating an application using **PowerApps** for this.